# A utility to compress rotated log files?

Tags: zip, nlog

I'm using NLog for logging and need to zip the loads of rotated text files it's generating shortly after they are created.

NLog should support this feature some time in the unknown future, but is there a utility of sorts that can do this independently ?

Comment: what are the requirements for zipping the files?

Comment: nothing special. I just don't want them to bloat the HD.

Comment: Seek "compressed" in http://nlog-project.org/wiki/File_target, apparently it tells Windows to compress the log files. I didn't find out how to make it work though.

Comment: The "Compressed" attribute can indeed be specified in NLog File target config, but the CreateFile API NLog uses to open the file does not support passing this attribute, so it is effectively ignored. Even if it worked correctly, it would apply NTFS filesystem compression to the file, it would not zip it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zipping archive files is supported since NLog 4.0, see [news post](http://nlog-project.org/2015/06/09/nlog-4-has-been-released.html)

Use `enableArchiveFileCompression`, e.g.

```xml
<target name="file" xsi:type="File"
      layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}" 
      fileName="${basedir}/logs/logfile.txt" 
      archiveFileName="${basedir}/archives/log.{#}.txt"
      archiveEvery="Day"
      archiveNumbering="Rolling"
      maxArchiveFiles="7"
    enableArchiveFileCompression="true" />
```