# NLog zip and delete old log files

Tags: c#, nlog

I would like to have NLog automatically zip and delete log files older than two weeks. I know about the archiving features. I would like to extend them to check for two weeks old logs and automatically zip and delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
<targets>
    <target name="..." xsi:type="File"
        ...
        archiveFileName="debug{#}.log"
        archiveEvery="Day"
        archiveNumbering="Rolling"
        maxArchiveFiles="14"
        ... />
</targets>
```

See NLog built-in archiving "Archival Options" (https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/File-target)

Comment: I have more than 1 log archived each day because i'm limiting log file size to 5MB as in addition to the archiveEvery=Day attribute. maxArchiveFiles won't work for me because i can have 14 files on the first day.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything in documentation about NLog supporting .zip file creation.

Create a helper utility to run periodically. Give it the path of your log file directory to find & zip files with time signatures matching your desired attributes. Keep a cache of the file names and then delete the files you have zipped.

Comment: Also possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594550/a-utility-to-compress-rotated-log-files